# How to access an attribute of a html tag in views with django

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

I have a html page which uses jinja to display a list.
I want to be able to get the user to click a button and the list will be added to a database. I have put the button in side a form and got it to link to my url which then calls a function.

HTML:

```
<form method='post' action='../../accounts/myaccount/' name= '{{item}}'>
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <a name = '{{ item }}'><button type='submit' class='btn'><img src={% static 'results/images/basket_02.png' %} alt='Image cannot be displayed right now'></button></a>
                            </form>
```

Views:

```
def myaccount(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            product = request.GET.get('name')
            print('product: ' , product)
            return render(request, 'signup/myaccount.html')
```

The function is called and it prints: product: NONE , whereas i want product to be set to the list.
I know how to add to database within my views but is there a way to actually access my list?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an input tag.

```
<input name="name" value="{{ item }}">
```